# Int in Android Java App

Tags: java

I am learning Java programming for Android Apps. 
I am currently working with an app that has 4 input fields which I would like to validate as a percentage total.
I understand how this works and can do this in HTML where you can validate between 0 and 100 using a 0 < i < 100 but what i do not understand in Java is how i will execute this - I have search for a few ways to do this but I do not get this. I am asking for help and not someone to code it for me. 
I also need to output a message if you enter a number wrongly (which I can successfully do in my app - but I am struggle with the validation of the data entered by the user at this stage)

Comment: `if (0 < i && i < 100) { System.out.println("Wrong number: " + i); }`

Comment: you probably should learn **programming** first before you hop onto mobile device development ... start with Hello-World apps in Java on your local machine. Everything else might lead to confusion and the failure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You ca check the input at this way:

```
if(Interger.valueOf(myinput.getText().toString()) > 0)
```

and let the user known:

```
Toask.makeText(getapplicationContext(), "Your message here", Toast.LONG).show();
```